# Event Emitters vs Promises for parallel execution?

Tags: javascript, promise, eventemitter

I'm making a slew of modules, each of which will need to run code during various phases. I could use a Promise.all for each phase like:

```
const phase1promise = Promise.all([module1.phase1(),module2.phase1()]);
phase1promise.then(// do next phases)
```

Or, I could use an event emitter from a "master" module that submodules listen to in order to know when to run code for phases. In turn, the master module would listen to those submodules' event emitters to know when they're done for that phase. I rigged up this event emitter system and it's working but I'm starting to think that promises might be better, especially with respect to code running in parallel. Also, maybe promises could be considered a more standard pattern. Thoughts?

Comment: Nitpick: neither Promises nor Event Emitters will run code in parallel: JS is single-threaded except for Workers.

Comment: Maybe that's the answer then ... either/or would work the same, just a matter of style/convention ...

Comment: SO is not a discussion forum or one to ask for opinions. You need to edit your question to ask a specific question which will return a specific answer that solves that problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does `module1.phase1()` do something asynchronous and the promise it returns is tied to that asynchronous operation?  If not, then there's NO benefit to `Promise.all()` at all here.  If so, then the underlying asynchronous operations may be able to get some parallelism in their native code implementations (it depends upon how they are implemented).  Events vs. promises makes no difference for parallelism.  Both are just notification systems.  They don't actually run your code, they just notify when things are done.

Comment: Yes I would say that the modules will do async tasks (I want to enforce finish-to-start for phases). I think I'll rig up both systems and compare benchmarks ... though I think they'll be very close to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just one "start" event and only one "end" event per module, and there's a master orchestrating all of this, then promises will be (by far!) simpler.

If the modules are supposed to register themselves with the master and/or emit multiple events for different parts, you will have greater flexibility (and a bit less coupling), but a much more complex system that's less clear to understand - needing to look at *all* files to figure out the dependency graph.

Comment: That's an interesting point about being able to emit more events than just my phase control communication. This might be a 6 of 1 / half dozen of another scenario. I think I'll rig up the promises system and compare speed benchmarks. Thanks @Bergi!!

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick Speed benchmarks? This thing runs only once on startup for initialisation - you won't notice any differences.

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick And yes, I actually meant the ability to emit multiple events for "subphases of a module" - not events outside of the phase control.

Comment: LOL yeah, speed-wise they'll likely be comparable. Just trying to make the "best" version of this that I can. Understood about the subphrases of a module, that could buy flexibility later.

Comment: Interesting. Emitters system loaded in 1659ms, promises system loaded in 1813ms. Since it's (slightly) faster and also allows for future flexibility I'll go with the emitters.

Answer (score 1):

Use events for things that happen more than once - for sequential data use a more specialized type of event emitters: Streams.

Use promises for things that happen once.

Promises are by design a request-response design pattern. You basically:

```
doSomething.then(processResponse);
```

With async/await, promises have become a very powerful tool to do various types of request-response: parallel, series, batch etc:

```
// Parallel
results = await Promise.all(a,b,c);

// Serial
for (i=0; i<tasks.length; i++) {
    results.push(await tasks[i]());
}

// Batch 10 tasks in parallel
for (i=0; i<tasks.length; i += 10) {
    currentTasks = tasks.splice(0,10);
    results.push.apply(results, await Promise.all(currentTasks.map(t => t())))
}
```

However, Promises are not designed to intercept multiple events. Once a promise has resolved its state changes to resolved.

This is where generic event emitters come in. For things like onclick listeners, waiting for requests over the network (see Express.js), waiting for keyboard input - promises cannot be used (unless of course you intend to stop listening to further events after processing one event).

For things that are inherently requests for some data use promises.

But note that both of these are just design patterns for how to manage asynchronous processes. The do not make functions asynchronous. And also note that asynchronous processes may or may not be multi threaded. For network I/O they are single threaded - javascript basically has parallel **wait**, not parallel execution of instructions. There are however modules that allow you to start new threads or processes (web workers in browsers and child_process in node.js)

---

#### Worker threads

If you look at web workers you will find that the API is event based. This is as it should be because workers cannot know when and how many jobs the master process will ask it to do. But you can easily wrap your own master process API in a promise because it is basically doing a request-response (provided of course that each request will only trigger the worker to send back just **one** response).

So sometimes it's OK to do both - use the design pattern that makes sense.

Comment: This is a great answer. Some nuance that _might_ not be clear is that operations that happen multiple times can still use promises, but they just need to emit a fresh promise every time. I think you largely cover that, but if you just read 'Use promises for things that happen once.' there's a potential for it to be misinterpreted.

Comment: @Evert Yes. Technically you can await inside a while loop to emulate events but that would be horribly clunky. Not to mention that this would mean that the outer async function is one that never resolves. Unless you mean one-time events that are called multiple times. They would still be events that happen once but you just happen to create many of them

Comment: Yes I meant the latter. For example, if I do multiple API calls they still use the request/response paradigm you talked about.

Comment: Thanks @slebetman. Right now all of these modules are doing client stuff and no network comm. I've experimented with workers but all of these modules need DOM access.

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick Yes. It's the same problem with Mac GUI development and .Net development on Windows and Linux/Unix GUI development (wxWindows, Gnome, Gtk etc.). The UI thread cannot be split. Therefore all UI processes **must** be done in a single thread. You can split tasks to be interleaved (do one thing, pause and do another, pause and resume previous task etc) but this won't make them happen in parallel, only spread evenly over time. For such "multitasking" you can simply implement them with `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. The main reason for doing so is to avoid blocking/freezing the UI

Comment: ... Look at how animations are done in javascript for how such processes are typically designed. You can also look at various animation libraries for how they signal end of animation.